# How to know the column name on yii2 Gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

On my system the user can create the column with the name they want, so I save the column name into database

I am using this code on column options:

```
foreach((new Field)->listFields as $item){

  data = [
    'attribute' => $item->name,
    'value' => function($model){
        return $model->$item->name; // the problem is here, $item->name is out of the scope
     },
  ];
  array_push($columns, $data);
}

return $this->render('index', [
  'model' => $model,
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

this is my index view:

```
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter'],
   'columns' => $columns,
]); ?>
```

I want to use the value, because I would like to format the data if the $item->type is X or Y.
ex:

```
'value' => function($model){
    if($item->type == 'img'){
       return Html::img($model->$item->name),
    else {
        return $model->$item->name;
    }
 },
```

the return of the listField is just an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => ITEM_1
            [type] => txt
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => IMAGE_1
            [id] => img
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => IMAGE_2
            [id] => img
        )
)
```

and the return of the sql in dataProvider is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ITEM_1] => Item 1 blablabla
            [IMAGE_1] => http://url.jpg
            [IMAGE_2] => http://url2.jpg
            [id] => 1
        )

)
```

As I am using dynamic column, I can't hardcode the column name like $mode->IMAGE_1

Comment: please show your model (Field)  and all the action code

Comment: why you have $model in  $this->render  ?

Comment: to pass other variables not used in this gridview like a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `$item` is out of scope, and as said in php doc [about anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (not specific to yii) :

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

You should simply add `use ($item)` :

```
'value' => function($model) use ($item) {
    return $model->{$item->name};
 },
```

PS: this question should be closed since it is a duplicate

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

could be you can access to the value using dinamic variable name

```
    return $model->{$item->name};
```

or  using an array access

```
  'value' => function($data){
    return $data[{$item->name}] ;
  },
```